# Download response very slow on Java Spring boot with kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I have Java Spring boot as a BE service deployed on Kubernetes.
I have a response size of APIs more than 50MB and it takes time to download(Tested by Postman).

How can we identify this issue?

Does it have some bottleneck on this system?

Response size of this request is ~85MB
[image]

I also have the same API but deploy another system. The download time is very fast. I don't know about the configuration of this service.

[image]

I tested with nginx config below but didn't change anything.

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
# Ingress bandwidth
kubernetes.io/ingress-bandwidth: 10G
# Egress bandwidth
kubernetes.io/egress-bandwidth: 10G
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rate: 2G
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rate-after: 2G
```